# Using sim card slot in a Thinkpad x120e

Tags: linux, thinkpad, 3g, sim

I have a sim card slot in my ThinkPad x120e. Can I use this to connect to the internet? Do I have to install any hardware to make this work? There is a free expansion slot on the motherboard, too, so what use can I put this into?

Answer (score 2):

I am not using ThinkPad as of now but out of my interest I just tried googling it out.

Lenovo has made the TPT’s 3G ready by including the Sim Card reader and 3G antenna and spot for the PCI-e WWAN modem.  The thing which is lacking here is the actual 3G modem itself.You can however use  Gobi 3000 WWAN PCI-e modem card and get it working.

Go through [this](http://blogs.tech-recipes.com/jimmyselix/2011/10/06/modding-adding-3g-to-my-lenovo-thinkpad-tablet/) and [this](http://www.thinkpadtabletforums.com/thinkpad-tablet-general-discussion/sim-card-slot-794/).You may found them useful .